# Flink Async IO operator tuning / micro-benchmarks

Tags: apache-flink, asynchttpclient

As Flink `Async IO` operator is designed for external API or DB calls, are there any specific guidelines / tips for scaling up this operator? Particularly for use-cases where incoming events are being ingested at a very high-speed and the Async IO operator with `orderedWait` mode can not keep up with that speed (although the target API endpoint it is calling is load tested to provide much higher throughput with very minimal latency). In our case adding `Async IO` operator to the pipeline **reduced the throughput by 88% to 90%**. This is huge performance hit!

We tried a couple of things:

1. Increasing the `async buffer capacity` parameter, there by
   increasing the number of concurrent requests at any given point in
   time that are waiting for response. This proved counter-productive
   beyond a very small number like 50 or 100.
2. Increasing the operator parallelism. This does not help much as the number of cores on our machines are limited (8 or 12)
3. Tuning the `AsyncHTTPClient` configuration (`keepAlive=true, maxConnections, maxConnectionsPerHost`) and the size of FixedThreadPool used by the Listener of its Future. Again without much improvement.

Our observation is that although `Async IO` operator works for one stream element at a time, the operator and its underlying HTTP client are multithreaded and need higher core machines for high-speed stream processing. If the only machines available for this kind of applications are 8 to 16 cores, we face challenges in meeting the required throughput and latency SLAs.

Are there any micro-benchmarks or tuning guidelines for using `Async IO` for high-speed stream processing, so we know how much throughput to expect from it?

Comment: Cross-referencing discussion on ML http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Flink-Async-IO-operator-tuning-micro-benchmarks-td35858.html